# When I try to click on Steam_latest.deb nothing happens?

Tags: installation, deb, steam

I downloaded the file and when I click it nothing happens?

Comment: We need more information. Please edit the question and tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using? Does steam install from the software Center Work?

Comment: When you say "click", did you mean single, double or right click?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Steam using a .deb file you should navigate to the directory holdimg it using the `cd` command in terminal. Then type `dpkg -i Steam_latest.deb`

However it is recommended for you to use the Ubuntu Software Center to download and install Steam.

Comment: The Ubuntu Software Center does not contain Steam. What do you mean?